# Is the vinyl records production process going green?

Tags: vinyl, production, vinyl-pressing

I wonder if there is some kind of attention in going green in the entire record production process (or part of it). By *"going green"* I mean if there are emerging approaches in everything related to pressing plant (energy used, waste produced, ...) and to material (alternative to PVC, recycling, ...) used in vinyl production.

I'm not interested in something like "[produce same amount of PVC in the same old way & ask for 1$ more to plant a tree](https://www.power991fm.com/2022/06/02/did-angel-olsen-just-show-the-music-industry-how-to-make-vinyl-green/)" kind of approach.

I'm curious if some changing in the entire process of vinyl production is happening somewhere. And if it can last.

I've heard about [Green Vinyl Records](https://greenvinylrecords.us/), but their website seems quite outdated, and their social accounts are no longer active, so I assume they are no more around.
I've read about [an experiment to produce vinyl from waste plastic from the seas](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-57572663), but I can't find any follow-up to this experiment, nor any "systemic" approach in this direction (or any feedback about sound quality).
Some record labels (for example: [Ninja Tune](https://ninjatune.net/sustainability)) are claiming they are already doing their part.
Also, [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/sap/2019/08/17/can-vinyl-records-also-be-green/?sh=74e10c9257f7) lists some alternatives, but it is from August 2019 & the only link that still points to something "green" seems to be the one referring to [Deepgrooves Pressing Plant](https://www.deepgrooves.eu/).

In conclusion, as said in [this article](https://eandt.theiet.org/content/articles/2019/03/dark-side-of-the-vinyl-are-records-bad-for-the-environment/),

> Certainly, there is some degree of plastics concern with records, but
> it is minimal – according to available statistics, new vinyl records
> account for approximately less than half of 1 per cent of the global
> production of PVC. The future is also looking greener, with new
> technologies and new production methods emerging. Maybe this is just
> the end of side one for vinyl: it’s time to turn the record over and
> enjoy side two.

In which ways we are turning to side two?

Comment: Green Vinyl Records are also cited on this Eni page https://www.eni.com/en-IT/low-carbon/green-vinyl.html#:~:text=Green%20Vinyl%20Records%20explains%20that,and%20a%20smaller%20carbon%20footprint It also mentions other "green" companies, and techniques for manufacturing vinyl records.